# Python dictionary comprehension filtering

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a list of dictionaries, for instance :

```
movies = [
{
"name": "The Help",
"imdb": 8.0,
"category": "Drama"
},
{
"name": "The Choice",
"imdb": 6.2,
"category": "Romance"
},
{
"name": "Colonia",
"imdb": 7.4,
"category": "Romance"
},
{
"name": "Love",
"imdb": 6.0,
"category": "Romance"
},
{
"name": "Bride Wars",
"imdb": 5.4,
"category": "Romance"
},
{
"name": "AlphaJet",
"imdb": 3.2,
"category": "War"
},
{
"name": "Ringing Crime",
"imdb": 4.0,
"category": "Crime"
}
]
```

I want to filter them by IMDB > 5.5 :

I try this code:

```
 [ { k:v for (k,v) in i.items() if i.get("imdb") > 5.5 } for i in movies]
```

and the output:

```
[{'name': 'The Help', 'imdb': 8.0, 'category': 'Drama'},
 {'name': 'The Choice', 'imdb': 6.2, 'category': 'Romance'},
 {'name': 'Colonia', 'imdb': 7.4, 'category': 'Romance'},
 {'name': 'Love', 'imdb': 6.0, 'category': 'Romance'},
 {},
 {},
 {}]
```

When the IMDB is lower than 5.5, It returns an empty dictionary. any ideas? thank you!

Answer (score 13):

A dictionary comprehension is not necessary to filter a list of dictionaries.

You can just use a list comprehension with a condition based on a dictionary value:

```
res = [d for d in movies if d['imdb'] > 5.5]
```

The way your code is written, the dictionary comprehension produces an empty dictionary in cases where `i['imdb'] <= 5.5`.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to using list comprehension is using the `filter` function from the Python `builtins`. This takes in a function and an iterable, and returns a "filter object" that only keeps the items which, when passed through the function return True.

In this case, it would be:

```
list(filter(lambda x:x["imdb"]>5.5, movies))
```

I included the `list()` around everything to convert the filter object to a list you can use. If you want to learn more about the `filter` builtin, you can read about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter).

Answer (score 2):

Other answers have already provided better alternative ways of doing this but let's look at the way you were going about it and look at what was going on.

If I delete some things from your code, I get:

```
[{} for i in movies}]
```

Looking at just that, should make it clear why a dictionary is created for each movie. You do have an `if` statement inside that dictionary, but because it is inside, it doesn't change whether it is being created.

To do this the way you were going about it, you'd essentially need to check twice making the first check irrelevant:

```
[
   { k:v for (k,v) in i.items() if i.get("imdb") > 5.5 } for i in movies if i.get("imdb") > 5.5 
]
```

which can be simplified to just

```
[
   { k:v for (k,v) in i.items()} for i in movies if i.get("imdb") > 5.5
]
```

and now, since we aren't changing the item, just:

```
[
   i for i in movies if i.get("imdb") > 5.5
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to use a 3rd party library, Pandas accepts a list of dictionaries via the `pd.DataFrame` constructor:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(movies)
res = df[df['imdb'] > 5.5].to_dict('records')
```

Result:

```
[{'category': 'Drama', 'imdb': 8.0, 'name': 'The Help'},
 {'category': 'Romance', 'imdb': 6.2, 'name': 'The Choice'},
 {'category': 'Romance', 'imdb': 7.4, 'name': 'Colonia'},
 {'category': 'Romance', 'imdb': 6.0, 'name': 'Love'}]
```